# How do I install Python on Windows 10 Pro, without using an evil installer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Environment: Windows 10 Pro. I don't want to download any .exe installer or modify my Windows path. I want all files needed for a program to work in a single directory, and if a data directory is needed, some option to let me specify that, same with configuration files. I would use Linux but I'm at work.

I downloaded and unzipped `python-3.7.2.post1-embed-amd64.zip` and added the path where I unzipped it to my PATH (.bash_profile as I'm using cygwin on Windows). So now I have python installed,

> $python-v Python 3.7.2

Apparently I need to also install pip to get anything done. I search and find this statement:

```
https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/win/#install3-windows
All supported versions of Python 3 include pip, so just make sure it’s up to date:
python -m pip install -U pip
```

That statement is false, the .zip file did not contain pip. So I search some more and am instructed to type:

```
$python get-pip.py
```

and so I do: and get:

```
Collecting pip
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/dc/7fd5df840efb3e56c8b4f768793a237ec4ee59891959d6a215d63f727023/pip-19.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
Collecting setuptools
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/6a/4b2fcefd2ea0868810e92d519dacac1ddc64a2e53ba9e3422c3b62b378a6/setuptools-40.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (575kB)
Collecting wheel
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/47/1dfa4795e24fd6f93d5d58602dd716c3f101cfd5a77cd9acbe519b44a0a9/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
The script wheel.exe is installed in 'H:\apps\python\3.7.2\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-19.0.1 setuptools-40.8.0 wheel-0.32.3
```

I then add pip.exe to my .bash_profile path, not modifying my Windows path.

And so now I run:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

and I get:

```
H:\\apps\\python\\3.7.2\\python.exe: No module named pip
```

I type:

```
$pip -V
```

and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\obj\Windows-Release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
File "D:\obj\Windows-Release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
File "H:\apps\python\3.7.2\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Why is it telling me something about my D:\ drive and a path D:\obj, that I know nothing about? I installed python, the .zip file under H:\apps\python\3.7.2\python.exe

I can't pip install or pip upgrade anything, and have no idea why it is talking about my D:\ drive or if I even have a D:\ drive.

Should I be able to download a .zip file, put the .exe in my path and start coding? Should I not have to install pip, if it's so very necessary for using Python? I don't know why it's missing in the .zip file, I don't know why it does not work.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#using-python-on-windows), the embeddable installer "is a minimal package of Python suitable for embedding into a larger application" whereas the [full installer](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-full-installer) "contains all components and is the best option for developers using Python for any kind of project".  So perhaps you should try the full installer.

Comment: The Python environment is indeed complicated and the recommended package management/installation tools have evolved over time to make it as smooth as possible. You seem to strongly want to go a different way, which is fine; and it's fine to ask for help; but it hardly seems fair to blame this on Python's ecosystem.

Comment: you can run python on docker, bind the volume to docker image so you will get acess to hard drive

Comment: Installing Docker, or building a container with 'buildah' and running that under Windows (any version), is the only viable solution here.  I cannot find an updated, most recent version of Python installable, workable on windows that will work with cygwin paths correctly, I don't want to have to change my code when deployed to production, and need to use paths like :   /c/home/<user>/project/some_py_dir/file.py etc.  I need Python to work on windows, and not have to use paths like:  'C:\\home\\<user>\\' and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I've just been having this problem myself; namely that the standalone executable of python 3.7 would not find pip even after being installed and the PYTHONPATH being correctly set.

The issue is the "python37._pth" file which overrides values set in PYTHONPATH, as detailed in this guide:

https://michlstechblog.info/blog/python-install-python-with-pip-on-windows-by-the-embeddable-zip-file/

I managed to get the standalone python executable working with PyCharm and pipenv in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Using the zip is not a supported installation method for windows:

> The embedded distribution is a ZIP file containing a minimal Python environment. It is intended for acting as part of another application, rather than being directly accessed by end-users.

If you want to install Python on your machine you'll have to use the "evil" installer.

Comment: The problem with installers, is that the person that wrote the installer, does not (ever), write an uninstaller that uninstalls everything and leaves junk around.  Microsoft has no package manager, that I have seen for Python that will completely remove everything including registry entries, files splatted in directories all over the system, DLL's etc.

Comment: As far as I know the installer puts all the files in a single folder, so removing is as easy as deleting said folder.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 10, you can run the Linux subsystem, and hence run Python on (say) Ubuntu.

First activate/install Windows Power Shell.

Then follow instructions from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

You will be able to install Ubuntu with a command-line prompt, and thence, Python.

(Windows-filesystem files are accessible from Ubuntu, but Ubuntu-filesystem files should ideally not be accessed from Windows)

Comment: Given there is no package manager that will install/uninstall things, I am left with downloading .zip (portable packaged), products, including python, unzipping that and using.  The Linux subsystem gives me problems.  I'm resorting to doing all development in Linux containers on my box, thank you.

Comment: Well, under Ubuntu you have apt-get ... but yes, the WSL (that I am running) does not run Docker easily !

Comment: I really need a .zip / portable Python, for Windows that I could put on a USB drive, so that I can script an installation instead of having to click buttons.

Comment: and with a Windows version of python, need it to honor posix paths, /c/some-path, so that my programs are portable.  I have tried using the Path library, and it does not work universally with every scenario, some other python libraries get confused, when I pass it a Path.